# Significato di "in batteria" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nella introduzione al *Grammelot dell'avvocato inglese* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> Qui salta fuori veramente la straordinaria forza, l'alta dialettica e la grande maestria di cui è dotato il nostro avvocato inglese. Come si presenta questo personaggio? Descrive lo stupratore come dedito esclusivamente agli studi, traduttore di classici greci, romani e ebraici, perennemente immerso nella lettura, sommerso da libri e come pausa di ricreazione invece di lanciarsi allo sgavazzo danzando e corteggiando femmine **in batteria** coi suoi amici, si inginocchia e ringrazia il Signore.

Ho cercato il termine "batteria" in parecchi dizionari, ma non riesco a cogliere il senso che ha l'espressione "in batteria" in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guardando la pagina della Treccani http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/batteria/ il significato nella frase in oggetto è quello riportato nel paragrafo d. :

> **d.** Più genericam., serie, quantità di oggetti o cose analoghe, riferito talora anche, in senso proprio o scherz., ad animali o persone

Significa che le femmine venivano corteggiate in serie, a raffica, una dietro l'altra.

Answer (score 3):

In aggiunta a quanto detto da @RiccardoDeContardi è utile il seguente esempio:

> [Allevamento di galline in batteria](https://it.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Allevamento_in_batteria)

che indica un allevamento intensivo in gabbie minuscole l’una vicina all’altra.

L’immagine evocata dall’autore vuol rendere l’atto del corteggiamento come una cosa quasi automatica e seriale a cui le ragazze non possono sottrarsi.

Comment: Mi risulta interessante che abbiamo in inglese un uso equivalente: "battery-raised hens".